# i can't use state props in require function of sound react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

i am actually trying to use **currentSong.audio** in the playSound function but the error is this : 
`Error: Cannot find module './screens/samples/clap_2.wav'`

i console log the state and i can see the link of the audio but when i put it in the require, it won't use it to play the sound.
It works when replace it by the url of the song directly **require('../samples/clap_2.wav')** so i am sure that i have the right path to the song.

*I am starting learning react native and i think it's because of async or something i don't understand yet..*

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance,

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { View, Text, ImageBackground, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';


const Sampler = ({currentSong, songs}) => {
    
    const [sound, setSound] = useState();


    async function playSound() {

        let url = (currentSong.audio);
        console.log(url)
        
        console.log('Loading Sound');
        const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(
            
            require(url)

        );
        setSound(sound);
    
        console.log('Playing Sound');
        await sound.playAsync(); }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        return sound
          ? () => {
              console.log('Unloading Sound');
              sound.unloadAsync(); }
          : undefined;
      }, [sound]);

    return(

    <View style ={styles.container}>


        <TouchableOpacity onPress={playSound}>
            <ImageBackground source={{uri:currentSong.cover}}  style={styles.image}>
            </ImageBackground>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    </View> 
    )
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        resizeMode: "cover",
    },

    image:{
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 70,
    justifyContent: "center"

    }
})
export default Sampler;
```

Comment: Try to put your audio file in the `assets` folder then try again or check your relative path

Answer (score 0):

It seems like is looking for the file in the same directory where is Sampler, you could try to pass an absolute path instead. This links explains how to do it.

https://betterprogramming.pub/using-absolute-paths-in-react-native-3be369244fb1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the problem actually it's not the path , because when i put the path of a song it works, but when i pass a variable(the state) with the same value which is the path it just won't play it...